# GetMetadata("/") hangs in DropNetRT

Tags: dropnet

I'm using DropNetRT and I'm executing this code:

```
api.UseSandbox = true;
await api.GetMetaData("/");
```

It never returns from the GetMetadata function.  All my other calls (i.e. GetDelta, Upload, GetFile) all work.  Any direction you can give me would be appreciate.